# Does the below mean the value stored in ebp minus 4 or the the memory address that ebp references minus 4?

Tags: assembly

[ebp-4] 
Does this mean the value stored in ebp minus 4 or the the memory address that ebp references minus 4?

I know that whatever the value is after subtracting 4 is going to be read as a memory address because of the brackets. I'm just trying to see exactly which number 4 is being subtracted from, the value stored in ebp or is it from the address that ebp references?

Comment: from the value stored in EBP

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. That is what I suspected.

Comment: Single dereference is usually enough of work for CPU, so almost no instruction works with two memory locations at the same time (one exception I can recall is `movs` and other `push/pop` with memory reference .. and probably some `call [mem]`, if it exists).